# Daylight savings Linux errors 1970-1980

Tags: python, datetime, ubuntu, time, epoch

I get one hour time difference in the year 1970 when running the following python script on my Ubuntu machine and my Windows machine.

```
$ python3 -c "
> import time
> import datetime
> print(time.strftime('%x %X%z %Z'))
> print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((87*24+2)*60*60).isoformat())"
```

**Ubuntu 16.04 / Python 3.5.2 says:**

```
04/03/17 15:37:07+0200 CEST
1970-03-29T03:00:00
```

**Windows 10 / Python 3.5.1 says:**

```
04/03/17 15:37:06+0200 Västeuropa, sommartid
1970-03-29T04:00:00
```

(The Swedish text under Windows means CEST.) So the clock is correct, and I think the timezone and DST are too. I think Windows gets the result correct, at least it's at that time DST should have happened. On Ubuntu DST is not showing up until ten years later at April 6, 1980 (one week after Windows' DST at March 30, 1980; which I also think is correct), but thereafter everything seems dandy.

Is this a software bug? Within Python? Ubuntu? Or are there further settings I need to do somehow? I suppose there is little chance this is a calendar quirk not properly special-cased by Python/Windows?

Comment: Is the time you are converting exactly on the DST boundary?  Do you have a link to a reference for the DST rules in your time zone?

Comment: What are the actual Ubuntu, resp. W10 locale TimeZone setups?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: no 15:37:07 is never on any DST boundary ever - that would be lunacy. If you like you can look at Sweden in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country#Rules_as_of_2017). I don't know what "W10 locale" mean?

Comment: ( one may enjoy a view on maintaining a TZ-aware datetime application >>> https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY )

Comment: @user3666197: bawhawhaw! ;)

Comment: @JonasByström: you asked this question but a lot of time passed and perhaps you forgot what it was saying.  You now tell me that 15:37:07 was not the DST boundary, but if you re-read your own question you will see that was the "current" time when you asked the question, rather than the time that the question is about.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I've written no such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three years in. Took me a couple of hours of digging to find out. The reason is there is no timezone transition data under Linux for that time:

```
$ zdump -v Europe/Stockholm -c1900,1981
Europe/Stockholm  Sun May 14 21:59:59 1916 UT = Sun May 14 22:59:59 1916 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
Europe/Stockholm  Sun May 14 22:00:00 1916 UT = Mon May 15 00:00:00 1916 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
Europe/Stockholm  Sat Sep 30 22:59:59 1916 UT = Sun Oct  1 00:59:59 1916 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
Europe/Stockholm  Sat Sep 30 23:00:00 1916 UT = Sun Oct  1 00:00:00 1916 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
Europe/Stockholm  Sun Apr  6 00:59:59 1980 UT = Sun Apr  6 01:59:59 1980 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
Europe/Stockholm  Sun Apr  6 01:00:00 1980 UT = Sun Apr  6 03:00:00 1980 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
Europe/Stockholm  Sun Sep 28 00:59:59 1980 UT = Sun Sep 28 02:59:59 1980 CEST isdst=1 gmtoff=7200
Europe/Stockholm  Sun Sep 28 01:00:00 1980 UT = Sun Sep 28 02:00:00 1980 CET isdst=0 gmtoff=3600
```

Who needs the years between 1917 and 1979 anyway? Computing is the future, not the passed. :D